# Assembly language issue understanding jump tables

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Can you please correct me reading this assembly code.
This is from the binary bomblab. 
line 29 compare the input to 2 and it has to be equal so I know 2 is part of the answer.
line 38 subtract 2 from eax, so I know the second input-2 <=0
func4: i think it does X *12 but then compare is to rsp+0xc which is 2 then it fail

can you please help

```
   0x00000000004010e8 <+0>:     sub    rsp,0x18
   0x00000000004010ec <+4>:     lea    rcx,[rsp+0x8]
   0x00000000004010f1 <+9>:     lea    rdx,[rsp+0xc]
   0x00000000004010f6 <+14>:    mov    esi,0x402a2d
   0x00000000004010fb <+19>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000401100 <+24>:    call   0x400cb0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x0000000000401105 <+29>:    cmp    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000401108 <+32>:    jne    0x401116 <phase_4+46>
   0x000000000040110a <+34>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x000000000040110e <+38>:    sub    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000401111 <+41>:    cmp    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000401114 <+44>:    jbe    0x40111b <phase_4+51>
   0x0000000000401116 <+46>:    call   0x40167d <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040111b <+51>:    mov    esi,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x000000000040111f <+55>:    mov    edi,0x5
   0x0000000000401124 <+60>:    call   0x4010b0 <func4>
   0x0000000000401129 <+65>:    cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0xc]
   0x000000000040112d <+69>:    je     0x401134 <phase_4+76>
   0x000000000040112f <+71>:    call   0x40167d <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401134 <+76>:    add    rsp,0x18
   0x0000000000401138 <+80>:    ret

 func4:
   0x00000000004010b0 <+0>:     push   r12
   0x00000000004010b2 <+2>:     push   rbp
   0x00000000004010b3 <+3>:     push   rbx
   0x00000000004010b4 <+4>:     mov    ebx,edi
   0x00000000004010b6 <+6>:     test   edi,edi
   0x00000000004010b8 <+8>:     jle    0x4010de <func4+46>
   0x00000000004010ba <+10>:    mov    ebp,esi
   0x00000000004010bc <+12>:    mov    eax,esi
   0x00000000004010be <+14>:    cmp    edi,0x1
   0x00000000004010c1 <+17>:    je     0x4010e3 <func4+51>
   0x00000000004010c3 <+19>:    lea    edi,[rdi-0x1]
   0x00000000004010c6 <+22>:    call   0x4010b0 <func4>
   0x00000000004010cb <+27>:    lea    r12d,[rax+rbp*1]
   0x00000000004010cf <+31>:    lea    edi,[rbx-0x2]
   0x00000000004010d2 <+34>:    mov    esi,ebp
   0x00000000004010d4 <+36>:    call   0x4010b0 <func4>
   0x00000000004010d9 <+41>:    add    eax,r12d
   0x00000000004010dc <+44>:    jmp    0x4010e3 <func4+51>
   0x00000000004010de <+46>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004010e3 <+51>:    pop    rbx
   0x00000000004010e4 <+52>:    pop    rbp
   0x00000000004010e5 <+53>:    pop    r12
   0x00000000004010e7 <+55>:    ret
```

Comment: There have been dozens of bomb lab questions in the past.  Perhaps try to use the search function to find one about the same lab you are stuck on.

Comment: Furthermore, this code has no jump table in it.

Comment: re: searching: maybe use an SO search for `code:"call   0x40167d <explode_bomb>"` or something to look for an exact duplicate, or some of the instructions that don't include absolute addresses to maybe find similar bombs.